# Include Microsoft.Graph and Microsoft.Graph.Beta API calls in the same project

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, beta

Is it possible to include  Microsoft.Graph and Microsoft.Graph.Beta API calls in the same project? I have the following startup class:

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
            base.Configure(builder);

            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IGraphServiceClient>((services) =>
            {
                return new GraphServiceClient(FunctionAppDI.CreateAuthProviderFromSecret(services.GetService<IOptions<GraphCredentials>>().Value));
            })
            .AddScoped<IGraphRepo, GraphRepo>();
}
```

GraphRepo.cs

```
     public class GraphGroupRepository : IGraphGroupRepository
     {
        private readonly IGraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;
        private readonly IGraphBetaServiceClient _graphBetaServiceClient;
       

        public GraphGroupRepository(IGraphServiceClient graphServiceClient, IGraphBetaServiceClient graphBetaServiceClient)
        {
            _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
            _graphBetaServiceClient = graphBetaServiceClient;
        }
      }
```

I have some api calls in GraphRepo in v1.0 version. I need to include beta version api call.

How would I change the startup class?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this [guide](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-dotnet#using-the-beta-client-along-with-the-v10-library) how to use the beta client along with the v1.0 library.